# Thin::Server#daemonize exits immediately

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I trying to make an executable, which starts a Sinatra application via Thin as a daemon.
I am using this code to invoke Thin with the Sinatra app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thin'
require 'app.rb'

server = ::Thin::Server.new('127.0.0.1', 9999, App)
server.log_file = 'tmp/thin.log'
server.pid_file = 'tmp/thin.pid'
server.daemonize
```

Here is the log output I get when I execute the script:

```
>> Writing PID to tmp/thin.pid
>> Exiting!
```

The server starts fine when I do

```
server.start
```

Any suggestions how I track down why it exits immediately?

Comment: 1. Is tmp folder writable? 
2. App or App.new in the server object creation part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `daemonize` only makes the script a daemon, it doesn’t actually start the server. You still need to call `start` afterwards:

```ruby
server.daemonize
server.start
```

Log file:

```
>> Writing PID to tmp/thin.pid
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: This is quite a old post , but i did not have to start thin explicitly after calling `server.daemonize`